# SQL Equivalent of Oracle's "WHERE () IN"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, aggregation

In Oracle, if I want to select all columns of the most recent entries for all ID's (based on a timestamp column), I can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE (TIMESTAMP,ID) IN
   (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP),ID FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID)
```

But this statement will not work in SQL SMS (version 17.4).

Is there an equivalent statement I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *correlation* approach :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE1 t
WHERE TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(t1.TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLE1 t1 WHERE t1.ID = t.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is `t`?

Comment: I understand it is a table alias, I meant "what is it" in the sense as "where is it defined", but I saw you just edited your post now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked perfectly, I will accept answer when SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

A where in condition can  be easy repalce by an inner join

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) max_time,ID FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID
) t on t.max_time = TABLE1.TIMESTAMP and t.ID = TABLE1.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, this works also. I already accepted the other answer, but I have upvoted this answer.

Comment: Anyway remaber that for performace the join  is better respect to a where in clause

Comment: A join is only better when the optimizer is not smart enough the rewrite the subquery to a join :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an analytic query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc949/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( ID int, ts DATETIME, rn INT );

INSERT INTO Table1 ( id, ts, rn )
SELECT 1, {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'}, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, {ts '2018-01-01 01:00:00'}, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, {ts '2018-01-01 02:00:00'}, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, {ts '2018-01-01 03:00:00'}, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, {ts '2018-01-01 04:00:00'}, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'}, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, {ts '2018-01-01 01:00:00'}, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, {ts '2018-01-01 02:00:00'}, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, {ts '2018-01-01 03:00:00'}, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, {ts '2018-01-01 04:00:00'}, 5;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   TABLE1 t
) t
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc949/3/0)**:

```
| ID |                   ts | rn | rnk |
|----|----------------------|----|-----|
|  1 | 2018-01-01T04:00:00Z |  1 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-01-01T04:00:00Z |  5 |   1 |
```